# Android studio- Layout inspector not working

Tags: android

Application not inspectable . Deploy an app or navigate to a debuggable app on your device to begin inspection .

My device should be connected and able to inspect .
Note-I am using latest android studio flamingo
Device-samsung m30 (old device)
Please update if my device having an issue .

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need android 11 for this